# Navigation bar for angular2 not properly displayed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, web-component

```
    <div class='main-nav'>
    <div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
        <div class='navbar-header'>
            <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>
                <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            </button>
            <a class='navbar-brand' [routerLink]="['/home']">Angular</a>
        </div>
        <div class='clearfix'></div>
        <div class='navbar-collapse collapse'>
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/home']">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/counter']">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span> Counter
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/fetch-data']">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Fetch data
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/margin']">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> MarginReport
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { MarginServcies } from '../../services/MarginService';
    import { Response } from '@angular/http';  
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';

    @Component({
        selector: 'margin',
        template: require('./margin.component.html')
    })
    export class MarginComponent {
        //public MarginList = [];
        //public constructor(private marginService: MarginServcies) {
        //    this.marginService.getMargin()
        //        .subscribe(
        //        (data: Response) => (this.MarginList = data.json())
        //        );
        public margin : Margin;

        constructor(http: Http) {
            http.get('http://localhost:2213/api/margin').subscribe(result => {
                this.margin = result.json();
            });
        }
    }

    interface Margin {
        AccountID: string;
        AsOfDate: Date;
        MarginType: string;
        DelivType: string;
        FedCall: number;
        MaintenanceCall: number;
        DayTradingCall: number;
        HouseCall: number;
        RegT_CallBalance: number;
        Equity: number;
        CashAvailable: number;
        DayTradingBuyingPower: number;
        PMA_Excess: number;
        AccountStatus: string;
        Company: string;

    }



    <h1>Margin</h1>
    <margin>

        <script type="text/ng-template">
            <!--<div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-body">-->
            <h3>Margin Call From Last Night</h3>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>AccountID</th>
                            <th>AsOfDate</th>
                            <th>MarginType</th>
                            <th>DelivType</th>
                            <th>FedCall</th>
                            <th>MaintenanceCall</th>
                            <th>DayTradingCall</th>
                            <th>HouseCall</th>
                            <th>RegT_CallBalance</th>
                            <th>Equity</th>
                            <th>CashAvailable</th>
                            <th>DayTradingBuyingPower</th>
                            <th>PMA_Excess</th>
                            <th>AccountStatus</th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr *ngFor="let marginData of MarginList; let i = index; trackBy: AccountID">
                            <td>
                                {{i+1}}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{marginData.AccountID}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.AsOfDate}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.MarginType}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.DelivType}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.FedCall}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.MaintenanceCall}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.DayTradingCall}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.HouseCall}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.RegT_CallBalance}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.Equity}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.CashAvailable}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.DayTradingBuyingPower}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.PMA_Excess}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.AccountStatus}}</td>
                            <td>{{marginData.Company}}</td>
                            <td>


                                <a class="btn btn-danger">
                                    Delete
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </script>
        <!--define the table here-->


    </margin>
```

Hi, above is my navigation bar code. And the MarginReport section just doesnot show up.I do not know why. i also have a margin.component.ts for my angular app.
I am not sure if it is the routing problem. i want the nav bar to show home, fetchdata, counter and margin report.

could anyone help me with that?

Comment: What you're asking is unclear. Does the app display correctly but nothing happens when you click the MarginReport link? Is there an error message? What do you expect to happen? How are your routes configured?  You don't give us much relevant info if as you suspect this is a routing problem.

Comment: Well, I see no problem in the navigation bar. Did you get any errors in the console? Also, I see some AngularJS syntax here in the margin component declaration. Use ng-template tag instead of a script with type 'text/ng-template' also if you want to put content in the margin component, did you add ng-content in the margin component? If you do, you don't need the template script at all.

Comment: the fetch data ,counter, home works fine. just the margin one does not show up...

Comment: yes, that is true. i have not clean up the code yet. but i am working on that

Comment: https://jonhilton.net/2017/01/16/display-the-weather-using-angular-2-and-net-core-web-api/

Comment: So the last navigation button called 'Margin Report' is not showing up? If yes, are you using angular-cli? Because it could be the browser cache messing with you.

Comment: i am not using that. i use dotnet restore command usually... This is really confusing.. i can not figure out why this simple thing not showing up.. and where could i check the browser cache?